# Как задать path в react-router4 относительно корневой папки проекта?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

При запуске локального сервера все пути в Roter прекрасно совпадают

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route exact path="/movie/:urlRusLat" component={Movie} />
    <Route exact path="/tv/:urlRusLat" component={TV} />
</Switch>
```

Но после сборки проекта главный путь Router `'/'` не совладает , это конечно происходит от прямого сравнения exact но без него не работают другие роутеры

Как по итогу задать пути относительно корневой папки приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. Ваш код должен нормально работать. Может быть вы имеете в виду, что при обновлении странички с некорневым роутом вам сервер возвращает 404-ю ошибку? Если это так, то тут проблема не в react-router, а в настройке серверного роутинга.

Например, ваш сайт лежит по адресу `http://site.com/` и сервер возвращает вам `index.html`, находящийся в коревой папке проекта, а вот когда вы переходите по прямой ссылке `http://site.com/page`, то сервер пытается найти в файловой системе папку `/page` с `index.html` внутри, не находит и ругается. Роутер же смотрит и меняет `browserHistory` ( или `hashHistory`), но физически никуда с корневого `index.html` не слазит.

Соответственно, вам нужно настроить сервер так, чтобы на ваш диапазон роутов он возвращал корневой `index.html`.

Прошу прощения, что так скомкано написал.

Comment: Проблема была немного не в этом, была проблема с путями у роутеров, решилось все дописанием путей относительно корневой папки сайта до проекта. Хотя данная проблема так же возникла)